turn wire frame of ico sphere into a cage
I have the Skelton of the ico sphere  . i want to turn the edges into tubes so that it can look like cage.
i tried solidify modifier and it didnt work.
I want the cage to look like this


Solidify modifier is basically like a normal-directed extrusion, it simply isn't what you need here.
What you could use is a Skin modifier:

The Skin modifier uses vertices and edges to create a skinned surface, using a per-vertex radius to better define the shape. The output is mostly quads, although some triangles will appear around intersections.
It is a quick way to generate base meshes for sculpting and/or smooth organic shapes with arbitrary topology.

Source: Skin Modifier - Blender 4.3 Manual

After you added the Skin modifier, you might need to select a vertex in edit mode and click the "Mark Root" button in the modifier for it to know where your geometry to skin "starts" from.
Then select vertices and hit ⎈ CtrlA to set the skinning scale to your liking.

As @moonboots  mentionned, you can also use a wireframe modifier (you may want to enable Boundary too), which requires keeping the faces unlike the skin modifier:

The advantage of this one is that the geometry is more predictable (you can see the Skin modifier can struggle at junctions of multiple edges into one pole). But you can't have varying size across the mesh, and a subdivision modifier on top of it looks like this:

Which makes it a bit harder to get a smooth result without applying the Wireframe modifier first, adding support poles at the junctions, and then letting the subdivision modifier do its job:


You can try 2 modifiers, the Skin modifier (to thicken the branches you need to go in Edit mode and press CtrlA), or the Wireframe modifier (you need to keep the faces of the mesh if you want to use this modifier, tweak the Thickness value if you want to thicken the branches):

